# Chart not appearing with .resize but does with .render

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-server

I am dynamically creating a chart within a map popup (triggered when user clicks the map) using dojo 1.7 (built into the Esri API that I am using).

```
 var c = dojo.create("div", {
          id: "demoChart"
        }, dojo.create('div'));
```

After setting the chart properties (data, theme, etc), if I call `chart.render`, the chart renders correctly but at the wrong size (too big for the infoWindow container div).

However, if I call `chart.resize(175, 145)`, the chart does get created at the correct size, but does not get created on first click, but the second click.

To replicate please [see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakc/Cwdyn), and refer to lines 49-53 in the Javascript.

```
  map.infoWindow.setContent(c);
  // Chart Resize will resize the DIV as needed.
  // However, the initial click will not show the chart
  chart.resize(175, 145);
  // Chart Render shows the chart on first click, but does not resize the div
  //chart.render();
```

I was under the impression that the resize method included calling render within it.  Therefore I am not too sure why I am getting this behaviour.

I need to know what needs changing in order to create  the chart div at the same size as the parent div that it sits within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the chart is rendering with the default size (400 x 300px) is because the chart node (div#demoChart) does not have any dimensions.

Furthermore, until the chart node div is visible, it will not have any actual dimensions (only style dimensions) for the chart to use. It then falls back to the default size of 300 x 400px.

To make your code work:

1. Add a css style for the div

   ```
   #demoChart {
     width: 175px;
     height: 145px;
   }
   ```
2. Create the chart after you have shown the info window and the chart node is actually visible. The chart gets it dimensions upon instantiation (in the constructor() method, rather than in the render() method as you might expect).

I have edited your JSfiddle to make it work ([view JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andymdesign/qPH8W/)).

Comment: can u add a link to the JSFiddle where u have made it work please

Comment: I thought I had updated your JSFiddle, but it didn't work. I have forked your JSfiddle and edited my answer to include the link.

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks Andrew.  Any quick ideas on why the tooltips are not showing up?

Comment: You need to create a new tooltip that is attached to the chart (see my JSfiddle above). http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/charting/

Comment: In ur Fiddle tooltips not appearing.  Ive implemented tooltips in a separate chart in same manner as my fiddle and they appear ok.

Comment: Fixed it.  new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart,"default"); seems to be the way to do it, I was trying var tip = new Tooltip(chart,"default");  thanks mate